# Rendering outdoor world in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, camera, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How would you simulate an outdoor environment with the Gazebo simulator? e.g. I would need to provide a texture map of the ground, sky and background, so that the robot sees more than just a flat color shade. The [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=build_world) explain how to populate a simple world with objects, but they all seem to assume I'm simulating an indoor environment with no background or special lighting conditions. I can't find how to texture the ground/sky/background to mimic an outdoor environment.

I'm thinking about participating in an autonomous vehicle competition, and I'm trying to find a way to simulate the course so I can easily test how my "virtual" robot reacts to camera input that roughly mimics input from the real course.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197624/rendering-outdoor-world-in-gazebo/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2014-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Post gazebo related questions to http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/ . I will answer it there since i have done it

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-12-20**:
Hi, could you post a link to answer to this question? I got similar problem, I am trying to build world from heightmap or using blender but I have some problems.

**Comment by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on 2020-04-04**:
The link to the question on gazebosim  : [here](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7474/how-do-you-render-a-realistic-outdoor-world-with-gazebo/)